# $doc->load($url) showing error

Tags: php, rss, oscommerce

```
 $doc  = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->load($url);
```

showing the following error

> Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Double hyphen within comment: http://news.search.yahoo.com/rss?ei=UTF-8&p=3d&fr=ush-newsblended, line: 139 in /home/public_html/includes/modules/rsslib.php on line 79

```
global $RSS_Content;

    $doc  = new DOMDocument();

    $doc->load($url);
```

The line no 79 is

```
 $doc->load($url);
```

and the rss feed is not listing

The url to load is http://news.search.yahoo.com/rss?ei=UTF-8&p=3d&fr=ush-newsblended

Comment: so can you show us line 139 and line 79 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you linked to is not an XML file.

So it ill not work with DOMDocument::load.